# Building a large web application based on small app projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, web-services, scalability

I am building a large web application. I want to structure it in such a way that I can write "apps" for it, or even potentially, have third party write apps for it.

I have one monothlitic web project, which has the Views, Controllers and the Models. I think it would be useful to break these down into projects.

I have been considering having a structure as follows:

- Basic Web
- App1

  - App1.Web
  - App1.Business
  - App1.Dal
- App2

  - App2.Web
  - App2.Business
  - App2.Dal

Basic Web will reference App1 & App2. Goal is to have Basic Web have a solid structure so that it does not have to be built quite often.

I am unsure about how this project can be built. Main questions are:

- How can I join multiple web projects, and join them together, i.e. MasterWeb = BasicWeb + App1.Web + App2.Web. Is this a good idea?
- Would each app have its own database and set of migration files?
- Would each app be its own Solution? (group of projects in Visual Studio)

I know this is a very general question, but are there any articles I can read that will help me modularise my projects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *How can I join multiple web projects, and join them together, i.e. MasterWeb = BasicWeb + App1.Web + App2.Web. Is this a good idea?*

  -- If you are using Maven, it has [maven war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html), where one WAR can be dependent on other WARs and consume other WARs are dependencies
- *Would each app have its own database and set of migration files?*

  -- Yes, probably you can have different databases for each app it is required. But having multiple databases can increase the efforts of managing transaction across resources (XA transaction management). I would recommend to go with just one database and multiple schemas.
- *Would each app be its own Solution? (group of projects in Visual Studio)*

  -- Yes, probably its better to keep each app independent.